# Properties of semisimple monoidal category

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, symmetric-monoidal-categories

In my work, I have constructed a semisimple category which has two monoidal structures: the usual direct sum; and a new "tensor product". This "tensor product" have several nice properties such as being: $\mathbf{C}$-linear, symmetric, admits a dagger structure, associative and distributive with respect to the direct sum. This category does not (a priori) come from $\textrm{Rep}(G)$ for some group $G$; however, objects in the category can be associated to representations of a $C^*$-algebra.

I am not familiar with the area of monoidal/tensor categories, hence I was wondering what are the natural properties/questions that are usually investigated when one comes across such a category. I would be particularly grateful if anyone could also provide references to any relevant introductory material.

To give an example of what I am looking for, I came across these lecture notes by [Etingof and Kannan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.04878.pdf) on symmetric tensor categories. In the introduction they discuss about Deligne's theorem and how it may be possible to recover the group from a symmetric tensor category (under some conditions). This seems quite interesting; however, unfortunately they require the symmetric tensor categories to be rigid (every object has a dual which satisfies the zig-zag relations) which the category I have does not satisfy.

Comment: Perhaps you have to restrict to the subcategory of rigid objects. In Deligne’s case one restricts to finite representations.

Comment: @LeoAlonso Sorry, I should have been clearer in my question. I am not specifically interested in Deligne's theorem. That was just an example of the kinds of things I am looking for. In general, I would like to know if an expert came across a symmetric, semisimple monoidal category (but not rigid) what are the usual properties/questions that they would look at. 
Unless, do you mean there is not much you can say if the category is not rigid?

Comment: The obvious reference is P. I. Etingof, S. Gelaki, D. Nikshych and V. Ostrik, Tensor Categories (SURV205, AMS 2015).

Comment: @Nanoputian In general, tensor categories come in two flavours, the "big" ones e. g. *all* modules over a commutative ring (with tensor-hom structure) and the subcategory of rigid objects, namely the subcategory of finitely generated projective modules, which is stable for the tensor structure. This a somewhat prototypical basic example, that might give some clue of what to expect.

Comment: @LeoAlonso Thank you for the explanation. Looking online, I can see there is quite a lot that can be said for rigid categories (such as the textbook that Dave Benson recommended). So it might be more fruitful to look at the subcategory of rigid objects as you have suggested. Just wondering, are there are general properties that can be studied for the "big" tensor categories that aren't necessarily rigid?

Comment: You can ask wheter it's monoidal closed (which is weaker than rigid).

Comment: @Nanoputian The big ones tend to be stable for co/limits, so theorems of representability and existence of adjoints are possible. Otherwise said, in the "big" context you are allowed to perform infinite constructions that sometimes may be relevant for the small —rigid— part.